# CSS3 nested selector

Tags: css

How could I make the following work?

```
.menu a {
     text-decoration: none;

     :active {
         color: #666;
     }

     :link {
         color: #666;
     }

     :hover {
         color: #666;
     }
 }
```

I know its not valid (or at least id does not work), so how could I fix it? I would like to make it easier for the further programming, so I would like to put :(selector) inside the "a" tag. 
Ps.: I really don't want to use SASS or any framework for this.

Comment: that isn't supported. you could fix it by running it thru a less compiler.

Comment: You could just put the selectors outside and indent those; this will have working code and still have code that is indented like you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing in the code sample is not valid CSS.

I know you mentioned that you do not want to use SASS or any framework, but that's precisely why SASS and other CSS ***preprocessors*** (e.g. LESS) were developed. [This article](https://www.urbaninsight.com/2012/04/12/ten-reasons-you-should-be-using-css-preprocessor) contains more information on CSS preprocessors.

Alternatively, you can repeat the "parent" selectors and indent accordingly:

```
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

    .menu a:active {
        color: #666;
    }

    .menu a:link {
        color: #666;
    }

    .menu a:hover {
        color: #666;
    }
```

Comment: or even better, .menu a:active, .menu a:link, .menu a:hover {color: #666;} just to keep it DRY